# Open Bootstrap 5 modal on double click with Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to open a bootstrap modal with angular on (dblclick) event?
If it is not possible, is there any other way to do it?

According to my idea I would open the modal somehow from typescript with a function triggered by (dblclick), like openModal().

Context:

```
<tr
    *ngFor="let user of users"
    (dblclick)="..." <!-- todo: open modal somehow and pass the selected user like below -->
    (click)="onSelectedChange(user)"
    [ngClass]="{ 'table-info': selectedUsers.includes(user.id) }"
                >
                  <th scope="row">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      (change)="onSelectedChange(user)"
                      [checked]="selectedUsers.includes(user.id)"
                      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      value="{{ user.id }}"
                    />
                    -
                    {{ user.id }}
                  </th>
                  <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
</tr>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userdetails" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title display-5 fs-1">User details</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

User model (I don't know is it matters)

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password?: string;
  role: number;
  name?: string;
  birth?: Date;
  email?: string;
  phone?: string;
}
```

I am expecting that when I double click on a row I want to display a modal with the selected user details to allow modification.

Comment: You can prevent single click event and then implement (dblclick). It should be straightforward.